# multilingual support in itext java

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I am using itext 5.5.4 in my project. I am trying to write a multilingual text in a pdf file. The relevant code example I found is [this](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph). This code uses `FontSet` class to bundle multiple fonts. Apparently this class is not available in itext 5. Can anyone please mention how can I write multilingual text using itext 5?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of text? For Indic scripts you'll need itext 7 for others it depends.

Comment: Sample string would be something like "पक का प्रकाश हर पल \u0A2A\u0A70\u0A1C\u0A3E\u0A2C\u0A40 New AAAA". This string contains Hindi, Gurumukhi and English text

Comment: The code example you refer to, is for iText 7, with the add-on pdfCalligraph. pdfCalligraph (a commercial add-on) is required for complex writing systems such as Indic scripts like Hindi and Gurumukhi.

Comment: Ok. Can it be done in itext5?

Comment: Ok , I have found that FreeSans has support for Hindi and Gurumukhi

Comment: Hindi and Gurumukhi are not supported in iText 5. You need iText 7 + pdfCalligraph